# android passing data new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm a beginner and i need fix this problem.

```
09-29 11:53:50.539: E/AndroidRuntime(658): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 11:53:50.539: E/AndroidRuntime(658): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
09-29 11:53:50.539: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at com.example.listactivity.MainActivity$MyCustomAdapter$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:91)
09-29 11:53:50.539: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
09-29 11:53:50.539: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
09-29 11:53:50.539: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-29 11:53:50.539: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-29 11:53:50.539: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-29 11:53:50.539: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-29 11:53:50.539: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 11:53:50.539: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-29 11:53:50.539: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-29 11:53:50.539: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-29 11:53:50.539: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my mainactivity.java

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

            TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTop);
            ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_image);

            textview.setText(data_topText[position]);
            imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

            row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View convertView) {

                    String product = ((TextView) convertView).getText().toString();

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            SecondScreenActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("name", product);

                    startActivity(i);


                }
            });

            return (row);
```

Comment: For example can you show your onCreate method and activity xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this

```
public void onClick(View row) {
           TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTop);

            String product = textView.getText().toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SecondScreenActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("name", product);

            startActivity(i);


        }
```

You are trying to cast your Layout to a TextView.  It is the LinearLayout that is receiving the click.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650505/how-to-passing-listview-images-passing-another-activity? this is my real can u fix this and explain me? please

Answer (score 2):

```
String product = ((TextView) convertView).getText().toString();
```

Here, `convertView` is not a `TextView`. It's a `LinearLayout`.

You probably want this instead:

```
String product = ((TextView) convertView.findViewbyId(R.id.tvTop)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650505/how-to-passing-listview-images-passing-another-activity? this is my another problem