# how to passing listview images passing another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-image

i have problem this code:

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();          
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTop);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

        textview.setText(data_topText[position]);
        imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

        row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View row) {
                    TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTop);
                    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

                    String product = textview.getText().toString();
                    int images = imageview.getId();


                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            SecondScreenActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("name", product);
                    i.putExtra("zurag", images);
                    startActivity(i);
```

won's passing images another activity. 
SecondScreenActivity.java:

```
    TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    ImageView images = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    Intent intent = getIntent();        
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    int pic =intent.getIntExtra("zurag", 0);

    txtName.setText(name);
    images.setImageResource(pic);       
}
```

Comment: use custom Adapter set and get text and images...

Comment: we click listview images that same image and text  display in next activity.....?

Comment: second activity doesn't have images only text. image wont passing.

Comment: where is your first activity....

Comment: Your question is not clear, please try to give more details, as what is the problem, any error messages, etc...

Answer (score 0):

your second activity just change like this

```
  TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
ImageView images = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

Intent intent = getIntent();        
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
int pic =getIntent().getExtras().getInt("zurag");

txtName.setText(name);
images.setBackgroundResource(pic);
```

Comment: it's working but only listview's first image show in second activty. another images won't show in second activity.

Comment: we use ` public void onClick(View row)` that's why whick row we click that image show in second activity.